# How to make Websphere connection factory as Weblogic XA complient?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, weblogic-10.x, configuration-management

I have configured websphere as aForeign Server in weblogic but now I am getting error while connecting to Foreign Connectionfactory as follows:

The Message-Driven EJB is transactional but JMS connection factory referenced by the JNDI name: jms/WASQCF is not a JMS XA connection factory.

I am not sure How to make Websphere connection factory XA complient?

I am using Websphere 8.5 and `using Queue Connection Factory`, I am not using MQ series

Comment: What, exactly, is "Weblogic XA compliant"?  Does Weblogic have some proprietary XA functionality that does not comform to the XA specification?

Comment: XA supports the transaction without which MDB will not get connected to Foreign Websphere JMS resources

Comment: Yup. I know what "XA Compliant" means.  The question asks about "Weblogic XA compliant" which implies there is some special Weblogic flavor that extends the XA spec or is otherwise non-compliant with it.  Since it appears that simple XA compliance is what was intended, my answer stands as-is.

Answer (score 2):

The answer differs based on the version of MQ client you are dealing with.  Since the client version isn't mentioned, I'll provide a generic answer.

Until a couple of years ago, IBM packaged the free client without XA transaction capabilities enabled.  If you have not downloaded the MQ client recently, it simply isn't able to participate in an XA transaction.  If you have an older non-XA MQ client, download a newer one.

Of course, IBM did provide an XA-capable client at that time.  Unfortunately, the cost for the transactional client was the same as for a full MQ server.  If you have the older transactional client it *is* capable of participating in an XA transaction but it is out of service.  In that case, download a newer client.

If you have downloaded a new MQ client that is capable of doing XA transactions, then please see the [Detailed System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27006467) page for your version of MQ client, then drill down to the "Supported Software" tab.  once there, scroll down to the "Transaction Servers and Gateways" section.

For example, this section in the V8.0 Requirements page says:

> The WebSphere MQ classes for JMS can only participate in global
>   transactions when accessed through the Java EE Connector Architecture
>   (JCA) resource adapter, which can only be used with a suitable
>   application server environment.
>
> For more detailed information on the use of the resource adapter with
>   application servers, see the Application Server section above, and the
>   WebSphere MQ resource adapter statement of support document.

This then links to [*WebSphere MQ resource adapter v7.1 and later statement of support*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27023129) which lists the JEE servers with which the JCA Adapter has been tested and additional information.

Assuming all the pre-reqs are in place and you have an MQ client that is transaction-capable, be sure to define an `XAConnectionFactory` for MQ.